# tf.keras to exe problems

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

i've installed anaconda and trained a neural network using (tf) keras on a windows machine. i'm able to use model.predict within the environment (anaconda navigator and visual code), communicating with the outside world via input and output file. however, none of the tools i tried to create an exe work. pyinstaller complains that there is "no module keras", py2exe mentions something is "beyond top level", while cxfreeze refers to "intel mkl threads". any hints other than to visit the astrologer to tell me when and where to buy a new computer?

Comment: Hi, Did you try with importing keras from Tensorflow as                                                       "from Tensorflow import keras"                                                                                              Can you please share a simple stand alone to code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @TensorflowSupport sorry for the delay. the answer is no (and i'm too lazy to go through all the trouble again). i've bought a new computer and use it for neural networks and games. i figure the solution to many problems such as the one i described is just move onto a card from the list on the nvidia site (cuda enabled GeForce) https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus